# Excel Formula - string multiple logical steps together

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Background: I want to generate a schedule from a list of all employees that is filtered for conflicts, specifically listed in one of two "Vacation" cells or they have already been scheduled in a conflicting role that same week.

1. List of Employees: A to J (Cells E1:E10)
2. Vacation:  (Cells V1,V2) for instance, employee C and F
3. Job 1: (Cell J1) Employee D
4. Job 2: (Cell J2) Employee A
5. Job 3: Here I want all available employees of A to M with any names matching cells V1, V2,J1 or J2 excluded. This would show me which employees are available to schedule in Job 3 (in this case B, E, G-J)

Make sense?

I can work with a drop down list of all eligible employees OR I can have a specific cell for each employee A through M showing "No" or "Yes" for availability if easier.

Thanks in advance! It's embarrassing how long I have been trying to IF and AND my way through this

Answer (score 0):

Here's one method, where you could put a Yes/No flag next to the employee. Here's the formula you could put in cell G2 or wherever you wish:

```
=IF(OR(COUNTIF(J:J,F2) > 0,COUNTIF(V:V,F2) > 0),"No","Yes")
```

Then drag it down.

[image]